# Unable to get env variables in public/index.html for react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to get env values from public/index.html file

Tried with window.APPDYNAMICS_KEY from config.js

**public/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <script src="src/config.js"></script>
    <script charset='UTF-8'>
      if(window.APPDYNAMICS_KEY){
....
```

**src/config.js**

```
export default {
  STAGE: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
  ...
  APPDYNAMICS_KEY: process.env.REACT_APP_APPDYNAMICS_KEY,
};
```

**.env**

```
...
REACT_APP_APPDYNAMICS_KEY=SAMPLE-KEY HERE
HTTPS=true
```

Comment: is appdynamics_config.js a part of your react app source code? If not then include it in your app.js file.

Comment: We added >> In     <script src="/appdynamics_config.js"></script>
Would that be sufficient?

Comment: No because create react app magically replaces all process.env instances to window but the condition is your file must be part of CRA's build process.

Comment: Updated my codes but now it has issues with Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<

Was trying to reference from this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48434897/how-to-have-a-external-json-config-file-in-react-jsx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out i didn't have to import any script.

Just use the following `'%REACT_APP_APPDYNAMICS_KEY%'` in my index.html

**public/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <script charset='UTF-8'>
      if('%REACT_APP_APPDYNAMICS_KEY%'){
....
```

**.env**

```
...
REACT_APP_APPDYNAMICS_KEY=SAMPLE-KEY HERE
HTTPS=true
```