# CRA Typescript - Read in config file with post deployment values

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a React app using [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/) which uses [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) and I am trying to read in config values, such as API urls. I currently have a `config.json` which contains this data, here's a sample with fake data to show the gyst of it:

```json
{
  "apiUrl": "https://localhost:3001/",
  "externalUrl": "https://localhost:3002/"
}
```

**The desired outcome**

I can build the web app once and deploy it anywhere, updating the config values at deploy time e.g. for dev `apiUrl` should be *https://localhost:4001/*, in prod `apiUrl` should be *https://localhost:5001/*.

The config should be available in all files and **not limited to just inside components** (so hooks like `useContext` won't work) and be Typescript compliant e.g. can access the config values via a typed interface/type.

**What I've tried**

There is quite a few similar posts to this, such as:

- [How to have a external JSON config file in react jsx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48434897/how-to-have-a-external-json-config-file-in-react-jsx)
- [React configuration file for post deployment settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51653931/react-configuration-file-for-post-deployment-settings)
- [Build Once and Deploy Everywhere for SPAs](https://blog.mikesir87.io/2021/07/build-once-deploy-everywhere-for-spas/)

The general suggestion is to put a `config.js` in the `public` folder, reference it as a `script` in `index.html` and finally call it via the `window` e.g. `window.Config.apiUrl`.

This throws an error in Typescript as us adding in this config in the `index.html` via a `script` doesn't actually add the type and I can get around this by using `// ts-nocheck`, though this is not ideal as it disables all checks for the file. Additionally, it would be preferable for the config file to be a type so can confidently reference it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are loading the value at runtime there's not really any way for Typescript to "know" about it in your code--and even if it did, the file is, of necessity, going to be a javascript file, not a typescript file (since its going to be read by your runtime, i.e., javascript) so it won't have typing info.

I think the best you can do is a user-defined type guard that performs an actual runtime check.  We use that solution in our apps.  Something like this (assuming you have already added the object via an import of a javascript file in public/index.html per the links in your question) in your React/Typescript code:

```
// the strongly type object you want to get out of your config file

type ConfigObject = {
  value1: string
  value2: number
}

// the cast of window is necessary as the default window type 
// won't know about the object you are adding

const runtimeConfigObject = (window as any).configObject

if(isConfigObject(runtimeConfigObject) {
  // use it, TS will now have the correct type
} else {
  // handle error
}

function isConfigObject(obj: unknown): obj is ConfigObject {
  return typeof obj.value1 === "string" && typeof obj.value2 === "number"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a file `window.d.ts` under `src/typings` with the following:

```js
declare interface Window {
  configObject: {
    value1: string;
    value2: number;
  }
}
```

and reference it from your `tsconfig.json` under:

`"typeRoots": ["./src/typings", "./node_modules/@types"]`

It's still your responsability to ensure that object has the expected structure and type, but at least you can access it avoiding `any`.